# Maximum perimeter of triangle in a rectangle

Tags: optimization

> What is the maximum perimeter of a triangle
>    that is inscribed in a rectangle?
>   Prove your claim

I found this problem while formulating the question of maximum length of rod that a truck can carry with the shape of wire being an arbitary curve.... I started off as a triangle for simplicity...
I have deduced that the services must touch the sides of the rectangle...My progress is on...(to be posted soon)

Comment: (Someone fix Latex...)

Comment: Can someone generalise it to a arbitary curve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that you never decrease the perimeter if you push a triangle vertex towards one of the rectangle vertices. Thus, the maximum is achieved when the three triangle vertices are three of the four rectangle vertices. The maximal diameter is $a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2},$ if $a$ and $b$ are the sides of the rectangle.